# Take a single snaphot from a webcam with a delay

Tags: webcam

I use

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=$HOME/Desktop/test.jpg
```

to take snapshots. It works well. However in some light situation I need to drop some of the first frames the webcam outputs so that the webcam white balance doesn't provide me with an impossible to view image.

Do you know how could I do that?

With the GUI of cheese I can do it without any problem, but I need to automate this via CLI.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with my webcam. I ended up using `streamer`.

```
streamer -t 7 -o image00.jpeg
```

This command will save seven frames shot by your webcam. My webcam needs between five and six pictures to adapt to the lighting conditions with the seventh picture of good quality.

Streamer is in the repository under the name `streamer`. (Surprise! ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot, really! ;) I've also added my "answer", it does almost the same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Tag=`date +'%y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
streamer -c /dev/video0 -t 00:00:01 -s 2592x1944 -b32 -o timelapse$Tag_00.jpeg
```